# Creating writable uploads folder in wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress

For a plugin i am creating, i want to create an uploads folder for uploading files temporarily and then after the process is complete, i want to delete those files.

This i have achieved using:
      $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

How can I be sure that the folder is writable if not the plugin will not function properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on if the uploads folder is writable or not and since you are storing your files temporarily, it is a better option that you create a folder in the uploads directory for which you can specify the permissions yourself,

```
    $up_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    // Create a folder in the Uploads Directory of WordPress to store your files
    if (!file_exists($up_dir['basedir'].'/your_dir_name')) {
        mkdir($up_dir['basedir'].'/your_dir_name', 0775, true);
    }
```

Then you can use this location for your plugins file storage.